# Archived forms and the export tool

Tags: commcare

When using the CommCare export tool and pulling forms in a form export, are forms that are archived included, or are they excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommCare Export Tool uses the CommCare API as it's data source. The API does not include archived forms by default. If you want to include archived forms you need to add a request parameter as described in the [documentation](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/List+Forms):

```
include_archived=true
```

To do this with the CommCare Export Tool you can can specify this as a filter:

- Filter Name: "include_archived"
- Filter Value: "true"